# Is there a way to use the empty space on a CD image to enhance error correction (for example entire second copies of file)

Tags: compact-disc, redundancy

I need to write a single file to a CD and the rest of the space is just going to be left unused. Is there a way to use the rest of the space to enhance the chances of the file being recoverable even if the disk is damaged?

For example adding excessive copies of the file to the file system until the disk is almost full?

Comment: If there is space I usually include an archive of the files as well, most often a .zip file. Combined with burning two disks and checking that each is fully readable in a second drive has served me well over the years.

Comment: There will be lots of space the file is one small PDF. I was also thinking about adding a zip and a tar.gz so your suggestion has helped confirm my initial thoughts on the subject Brian. Thanks.